Fluent FFmpeg Thumbnail Extraction Error: "muxing overhead: unknown, conversion failed"
I'm trying to extract a thumbnail from a video using Fluent FFmpeg, but I'm encountering the error "muxing overhead: unknown, conversion failed." Despite this error, the thumbnail is being generated correctly.
Here's my code:
const screenshotPath = resolve(`${output}/${videoId}_thumbnail.png`);
ffmpeg(inputUrl)
  .screenshots({
    timestamps: [timestamp],
    filename: screenshotPath,
    size: '640x360'
  })
  .output(screenshotPath)
  .on('error', (err) => {
    log.error(`VideoId:${videoId} -> Error while extracting screenshot`, err);
  });

I've already verified the following:

Input file integrity: The input video file is not corrupted.
Supported formats: The video format is compatible with Fluent FFmpeg.
System resources: My system has sufficient resources for the conversion.
Conversion tool: I'm using the latest version of Fluent FFmpeg.

Despite these checks, the error persists. I'm wondering if this is a known issue or if there's something else I might be missing.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
